# Replacing nested foreach statements

Tags: c#

I'm currently dealing with a situation in which I need to get object from db, map it to another object, send it to view model and then map it back and save to db.

Below you will find my sample program. It works, but I'm not happy about the way it is written. I feel like wrapping multiple foreach statements is not very readable for another programmers.

Can anybody help me to structure my code in more readable and perhaps more performance-wise fashion? For example using linq `statements .Select()` or `.SelectMany()`.

Sample program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<OldIncomeStructure> listOldPersonIncome = new List<OldIncomeStructure>();
        Balance balance = new Balance();
        PopulateBalance(ref balance);
        foreach(var personIncome in balance.IncomeOverview.PersonIncome)
        {
            OldIncomeStructure structure = new OldIncomeStructure();
            structure.PersonId = personIncome.PersonId;
            foreach(var prijem in personIncome.Incomes)
            {
                switch (prijem.IncomeTemplateId)
                {
                    case 1:
                        structure.MainJob = prijem.Amount;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        structure.SideJob = prijem.Amount;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        structure.Maternity = prijem.Amount;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        structure.Retirement = prijem.Amount;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        structure.Other = prijem.Amount;
                        break;    
                }
            }
            listOldPersonIncome.Add(structure);
        }   
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void PopulateBalance(ref Balance balance)
    {
        balance.PortfolioId = 1;
        balance.IncomeOverview = new IncomeOverview()
        {
            PersonIncome = new List<PersonalIncome>()
        };
        List<PersonalIncome> personalIncomes = new List<PersonalIncome>();
        personalIncomes.Add(new PersonalIncome
        {
            PersonId = 1,
            Incomes = new List<Income>()
            {
                new Income
                {IncomeTemplateId = 1,Amount = 110},
                new Income
                {IncomeTemplateId = 2, Amount = 120},
                new Income
                {IncomeTemplateId = 3, Amount = 130},
                new Income
                {IncomeTemplateId = 4, Amount = 140},
                new Income
                {IncomeTemplateId = 5, Amount = 150}
            }
        });
        personalIncomes.Add(new PersonalIncome
        {
            PersonId = 2,
            Incomes = new List<Income>()
            {
                new Income
                {IncomeTemplateId = 1,Amount = 210},
                new Income
                {IncomeTemplateId = 2, Amount = 220},
                new Income
                {IncomeTemplateId = 3, Amount = 230},
                new Income
                {IncomeTemplateId = 4, Amount = 240},
                new Income
                {IncomeTemplateId = 5, Amount = 250}
            }
        });
        balance.IncomeOverview.PersonIncome = personalIncomes;
        //naplnit pres linq
        var sum = 0;
        foreach(var person in balance.IncomeOverview.PersonIncome)
        {
            foreach(var income in person.Incomes)
            {
                sum += income.Amount;
            }
        }
        balance.IncomeOverview.Sum = sum;
    }
}
```

Model classes:

```
public class OldIncomeStructure
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int MainJob { get; set; }
    public int SideJob { get; set; }
    public int Maternity { get; set; }
    public int Retirement { get; set; }
    public int Other { get; set; }
}

public class Balance
{
    public int PortfolioId { get; set; }
    public IncomeOverview IncomeOverview { get; set; }
}

public class IncomeOverview
{
    public int Sum { get; set; }
    public List<PersonalIncome> PersonIncome { get; set;}
}

public class PersonalIncome
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public List<Income> Incomes { get; set; }
}

public class Income
{
    public int IncomeTemplateId { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not worrying about performance until it becomes a problem, unless high-performance is specifically a requirement. In particular, Linq can have some [performance costs](https://mattwarren.org/2016/09/29/Optimising-LINQ/), but is great for readability and should be used.

But your concern about readability is a good one. A few tips:

#### [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

try to identify specific responsibilities and encapsulate these into functions/classes as appropriate. In particular the responsibility of this block:

```cs
            OldIncomeStructure structure = new OldIncomeStructure();
            structure.PersonId = personIncome.PersonId;
            foreach(var prijem in personIncome.Incomes)
            {
                switch (prijem.IncomeTemplateId)
                {
                    case 1:
                        structure.MainJob = prijem.Amount;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        structure.SideJob = prijem.Amount;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        structure.Maternity = prijem.Amount;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        structure.Retirement = prijem.Amount;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        structure.Other = prijem.Amount;
                        break;    
                }
            }
```

could be summed up as "create a new `OldIncomeStructure` instance from a `PersonalIncome` instance". You could encapsulate this into a function as follows:

```cs
public static OldIncomeStructure CreateOldIncomeStructure(PersonalIncome personIncome)
{
    // the above code
}
```

you can then get do something like

```cs
var listOldPersonIncome = balance.IncomeOverview.PersonIncome.Select(p => CreateOldIncomeStructure(p)).ToList();
```

to replace the outer `foreach`.

#### Naming

Take care of naming of variables/types, in particular I think the following substitutions would help readability:

- `OldIncomeStructure` -> `LegacyIncome`
- `List<PersonalIncome> PersonIncome` -> `List<PersonalIncome> PersonalIncomes`
- `var prijem` -> `var income`

#### Avoid ref parameters

`PopulateBalance` could instead be `GetBalance` and create/return a `Balance` object, rather than using `ref`